# Rebinding keys in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm trying to rebind a few keys in AUCTeX, mainly `\textit` and the like. So, as a test I've added to `.emacs`

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-S-i") 'find-file)
  )
)
```

It works, but which is the command I have to write instead of `find-file` to insert `\textit` as <kbd>C-c C-f C-i</kbd> does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A very useful function in Emacs is `describe-key` that will tell you what function is being called by which keys.
So, it seems that in AucTEX, <kbd>C-c C-f C-i</kbd> calls `TeX-font` and then passes <kbd>C-i</kbd> as argument.

So a simple solution would be to bind a key to TeX-font and keep the <kbd>C-i</kbd> (and others) to get the font you want. You can customize the list of possible fonts and secondary key shortcuts with `TeX-font-list`.
You would thus have a simple:

```lisp
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-S-i") 'TeX-font)
```

(with whatever key you want).

If you really want to only rebind the italics and nothing else, you can always do:

```lisp
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-S-i") '(lambda () (interactive)(TeX-font nil ?\C-i)))
```

no need to redefine the whole behaviour of TeX-font.

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You may use something like this:

```lisp
  (defun insert-textit()
  "places textit{} into LaTeX buffer."
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (progn
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (region-beginning))    
          (insert "\\textit{" ))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (region-end))
          (insert "}")))
    (insert "\\textit{}")
    (goto-char (forward-point -2)))
  (goto-char (forward-point 1)))

    (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-S-i") 'insert-textit)
      )
    )
```

### Edit

This extended code handles the case of marked region too.

#### Edit #2

I removed the not needed concat and last progn

Comment: If there is a marked region `C-c C-f C-i` will wrap that region in `\textit`. This function lack that functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Your post answers another question I didn't even ask (how to write a function applied to a region).

Comment: I do not think the `concat` and the last `progn` is needed. The function seems to work well when they are removed.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a simple (and general) approach based on macros (thanks to `insert-kbd-macro`, which I've just discovered). Since I needn't remove <kbd>C-c C-f C-i</kbd> I define a macro and then I bind it to <kbd>C-S-i</kbd>.

```lisp
(fset 'my-set-textit
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item `(,(kbd "C-c C-f C-i") 0 "%d") arg)))
```

Then I use `'my-set-textit` in `define-key`. (Edit: replaced code with special chars.)